# ExifInterface not allow writing the Tag Date Taken

Tags: android

I am developing an application of custom camera with including Image property writing "ExifInterFace".I got success to wrting Tag of 
GPS,MAKE,and MODEL however i got issue with DATE TAKEN

I am not Found Date Taken Tag from Exif interface([Developer link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)).

What i have Tried so far ..

1. I tryed to write the date with TAG_DATETIME,TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP but its not work
2. Used JHeader Library, Invented by MIT for Writing Exif Interface but its not work
3. I used "ContentValues" for writing image

   ```
    public static Uri addImageAsApplication(ContentResolver cr, String name,
               long dateTaken, String directory,
               String filename, Bitmap source, byte[] jpegData,String filePath) {

           Uri IMAGE_URI = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);
           values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
           values.put(Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
           return cr.insert(IMAGE_URI, values);
       }
   ```

but its not work.

so can you please help me on this
Note : I have also refer the Question on stack :
Cant set Date Taken/DateTime tag using the ExifInterface in Android

Thanks